# iText Filling existing table PDF

Tags: java, itext, webdynpro

I'm trying to fill an existing table in my PDF.
I found some examples on iText but they always create a new table and then fills it.

In my case I have already created a table and now I want to add rows to this.

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: You *have already created a table* - do you mean you already have a PDF with a table? Or a gui table? Or some abstract data table?

Comment: I already created a PDF file with a table (id: Table1)

Comment: Is the structure known to you? I.e. do you know the relevant table coordinates (column coordinates, column styles, position of new rows, ...)? Then your task is feasible. Please be aware that in the PDF there is no table structure as such anymore, merely some lines and / or colored backgrounds and some text positioned at funny positions.

Answer (score 0):

[How-to-add-row-in-jtable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3549206/how-to-add-row-in-jtable)
 may help you. Instead iText, You can print your table using Jtable's built in print method. Go to [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/printtable.html) link for more.

Thanks.