# Convert a PDF with forms to a PDF with text only (preserve data) using iText

Tags: java, pdf, itext, pdfbox

- I have multiple PDFs that get populated with multiple records (a.pdf,b.pdf,c[0-9].pdf,d[0-9].pdf,ez.pdf) using acroforms and pdfbox.
- The resulting files (aflat.pdf,bflat.pdf,c[0-9]flat.pdf,d[0-9]flat.pdf,ezflat.pdf) should have their forms(dictionaries and whatever adobe uses) removed but the fields filled as raw text saved on the pdf (setReadOnly is not what I want!).

[PdfStamper](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfStamper.html#setFormFlattening(boolean)) can only remove fields without saving their content but I've found some references to PdfContentByte as a way to save the content. Alas, the documentation is too brief to understand how I should do this.

As a last resort I could use [FieldPosition](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/AcroFields.FieldPosition.html) to write directly on the PDF. Has anyone ever encountered such problem? How do I solve it?

**UPDATE**: **Saving a single page of b.pdf yields a valid bfilled.pdf but a blank bflattened.pdf**. Saving the whole document solved the issue.

```
    populateB();
    try (PDDocument doc = new PDDocument(); FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream("bfilled.pdf")) {
        //importing the page will corrupt the fields
        /*wrong approach*/doc.importPage((PDPage)pdfDocuments.get(0).getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages().get(0));
        /*wrong approach*/doc.save(stream);
        //save the whole document instead
        pdfDocuments.get(0).save(stream);//<---right approach

    }
    try (FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream("bflattened.pdf")) {
        PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(new PdfReader("bfilled.pdf"), stream);
        stamper.setFormFlattening(true);
        stamper.close();
    }
```

Comment: Your say your PDFs were *populated using acroforms and pdfbox*. Have appearance streams been created for those fields by PDFBox? If not, you might want to read [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20527155/1729265) by Bruno.

Comment: The documentation says: Sets the option to generate appearances. Not generating appearances will speed-up form filling but the results can be unexpected in Acrobat. Don't use it unless your environment is well controlled. The default is true.

Answer (score 3):

Use `PdfStamper.setFormFlattening(true)` to get rid of the fields and write them as content.

Comment: It doesn't save the content of the field. There must be some steps I'm missing. Would you care to elaborate? :) P.S. Should I use pdfStamper.getOverContent(pageNum) to get the content and then do something?

Comment: Can you post the pdf?

Comment: The pdf is as standard as they get, there shouldn't be a problem flattening it. Show me your flattening code.

Comment: I tried it and `PdfStamper` with `setFormFlattening(true)` flattens the field contents into the page content as expected. If it doesn't for you, you should edit your question to include enough code to allow reprocing the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Always use the whole page when working with acroforms

```
    populateB();
try (PDDocument doc = new PDDocument(); FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream("bfilled.pdf")) {
    //importing the page will corrupt the fields
    doc.importPage((PDPage) pdfDocuments.get(0).getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages().get(0));
    doc.save(stream); 
    //save the whole document instead
    pdfDocuments.get(0).save(stream);

}
try (FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream("bflattened.pdf")) {
    PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(new PdfReader("bfilled.pdf"), stream);
    stamper.setFormFlattening(true);
    stamper.close();
}
```

Comment: So this essentially was a problem in the context of PDFBox use, not iText, wasn't it? BTW, your code as shown here now saves two distinct documents to the same output stream. I assume your comments in that code mean not to use the first save but the second one. But there are so many people around who copy&paste code without reading comments...

Comment: Essentialy yes. I assumed PDPage had any information needed. I left the wrong instructions uncommented to leave them more readable, I'll add a little comment on the side just to be sure.